# Can't save textBox input to variable

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I have a WinForms program with 2 forms. On one form I am getting all user input needed for the information I am outputting in the main form. Like a settings window. However when I have a MaterialSkin textbox (I don't know if this matters) and write something in the textbox, I am trying to get the input by making a `textbox_textchanged` event that stores the current text into a variable. However I can't access that variable in my other class. It is public but it seems like the variable is not even stored correctly.

I've tried making a textbox that does quite the same in the main form and it worked just fine. But now that I have it in a seperate form I can't call the variable and/or it doesn't get saved properly

`outputWindow.Text += settings.desiredHypixelLevel;` 
^ Line in the main form that should print the current text of desiredLevel into the textbox called `outputWindow`. `settings.desiredHypixelLevel` is defined below.

```
private void desiredLevel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var parseSucessful = Int32.TryParse(this.Text, out desiredHypixelLevel);
            if (!parseSucessful)
            {
                this.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

^ Code that is getting a variable from a textbox in my second form

At the start of my second form's class I am defining a public variable called `desiredHypixelLevel` `public int desiredHypixelLevel;`. I am referencing the class with `Settings settings = new Settings();` (`Settings` is the name of the second form)

Image to my form layout: https://prntscr.com/m5ik1g (It doesn't show up when embedding)

The expected result is that the variable is taken from the textbox and stored in the `desiredHypixelLevel` variable. However it is just storing 0 in there.

Comment: How are you referencing this second form?

Comment: @LarsTech Edited

Comment: Not enough code.  `new Settings();` is most likely not the reference of the form you see on the screen.

Comment: Settings is the class name I am trying to reference so that should be right? The name in the properties is also Settings.

Comment: Like I said, you haven't shown enough code for us to see how you have these two things connected.  "new" is the optimal word here.  It's a "new" reference.

Comment: I am showing the Settings form by clicking a button in the main form.

Comment: I guess you're not going to show the code then.

Comment: Uhh I have the entire project on gist.github.com if you want that? I can provide some line numbers where I think I am wrong.

Comment: @Dylan provide more code and please rename the form `Settings` to `FrmSettings` to get sure your are not calling another class.

Answer (score 0):

In your 1st form:

```
public string text { get {return textBox1.Text; } }
```

In your 2nd form:

```
public Form2(Form1 f)   
{
    this.textBox1.Text = f.text
}
```